# How to display subcategory of root category using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I am displaying root category in my custom module. Now when i m click on any one category than i want to display their subcategory using ajax. i want that subcategory with checkbox like this

[image]

Using this code i m getting all root category

```
<?php 
$parentCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('eq'=>$parentCategoryId))
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<?php  foreach($categories as $cats):?>
     <li>
        <input type='text' style="border:0px;" id="checkcat<?php echo $cats->getEntityId();?>" name="checkcat<?php echo $cats->getEntityId();?>" value='<?php echo $cats->getName();?>' readonly />
     </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

So how to get subcategory click on root category using ajax

Comment: do you have a restful php service written? that you send a parent category that returns children?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same code for both the initial menu and ajax, just choose between the ajax parameter and root category id:

```
$parentCategoryId = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('parent_category_id')) ? this->getRequest()->getParam('parent_category_id') : Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
```